# How to resize image using Gd library ? PHP

Tags: php, image, gd

after receiving the image from the client , I would like to resize it and then store it .
I am using this function:

```
function PIPHP_ImageResize($image, $w, $h)
{
         $oldw = imagesx($image);
         $oldh = imagesy($image);
         $temp = imagecreatetruecolor($w, $h);
         imagecopyresampled($temp, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0,
            $w, $h, $oldw, $oldh);
         return $temp;
}
$image = PIPHP_ImageResize($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],10,10);
move_uploaded_file($image, $newname);
```

unfortunately I got these warning:

1. Warning: imagesx() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given...
2. Warning: imagesy() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given ...
3. Warning: imagecopyresampled() expects parameter 2 to be resource, string given ...
4. Warning: move_uploaded_file() expects parameter 1 to be string, resource given ...

How could I fix the problem !!

Comment: You may want to read the documentation of how these functions work, what they expect in parameters; maybe even check the code examples on those docs pages!

Comment: @Maerlyn , I know that I don't give the function the correct parameter, you can see that from the warning( expects parameter 1 to be resource ) but I don't understand what the resource is ?

Comment: A resource is a variable instantiated with the correct image creator function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`imagesx` expect an image resource as first parameter. You have to create one using the appropriate function, [imagecreatefromjpeg](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromjpeg.php) or [imagecreatefrompng](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefrompng.php) for example.

```
function PIPHP_ImageResize($image, $w, $h)
{
    $oldw = imagesx($image);
    $oldh = imagesy($image);
    $temp = imagecreatetruecolor($w, $h);
    imagecopyresampled($temp, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $w, $h, $oldw, $oldh);
    return $temp;
}

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $newname)) {
    $uploadedImage = imagecreatefromjpeg($newname);
    if (!$uploadedImage) {
        throw new Exception('The uploaded file is corrupted (or wrong format)');
    } else {
        $resizedImage = PIPHP_ImageResize($uploadedImage,10,10);
        // save your image on disk
        if (!imagejpeg ($resizedImage, "new/filename/path")) {
              throw new Exception('failed to save resized image');
        }
    }
} else {
    throw new Exception('failed Upload');
}
```

I've added a minimal **and insufficient** error handling, you should check, for example, the format of the uploaded file and use the appropriate image creator function, or check if the uploaded file is an image.

**Addendum**

You can determine the type of the presumed uploaded image using [getimagesize](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) function.

getimagesize return an array. If the image type is supported the array[2] value return the type of the image. if the file is not an image, or its format is not supported, the array[0] value is zero. Once you know the file format of the image you can use one of the imagecreatefromxxx functions to create the appropriate image.

Comment: I am using many image file ... png,JPEG,JPG,x-png... is there an imgaeCreate function that suits to all the kind of images...thank you

Comment: @user3648409 I've just added some hints on determining the file format in the answer

Comment: The PHP docs recommends using FileInfo for file format detection: https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.fileinfo.php